# get the value radio_button jquery of variable

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I need to get the value of the selected radio_button. First, for display to the user, and then to work with this variable. The value is stored in the database, so the problem in the script.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input[name="timeselect"]:radio').change(function() {

    var str3 = "";
    $('input[name="timeselect"]:checked').val();
    str3 += $(this).text() + "\n";

    $("#timevalue").text();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="new_order" id="new_order" action="/orders" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="GCE2" />
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <tbody>
        <input class="timeselect" type="radio" value="1" name="order[route_id]" id="order_route_id_1" />
        <label for="order_route_id_1">07:00</label>
        <input class="timeselect" type="radio" value="2" name="order[route_id]" id="order_route_id_2" />
        <label for="order_route_id_2">07:00</label>
        <input class="timeselect" type="radio" value="3" name="order[route_id]" id="order_route_id_3" />
        <label for="order_route_id_3">09:00</label>
        <input class="timeselect" type="radio" value="4" name="order[route_id]" id="order_route_id_4" />
        <label for="order_route_id_4">09:00</label>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button">Далее</button>
  <p> <span id="timevalue"></span>
  </p>
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Заказать" class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right" />
</form>
```

Comment: The following statements do nothing useful: `var str3 = "";
    $('input[name="timeselect"]:checked').val();
    str3 += $(this).text() + "\n";

    $("#timevalue").text();` also `input[name="timeselect"]:radio` does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect. `timeselect` is a defined as CSS class so either use [Class Selector (“.class”)](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

```
var str3 = $('input.timeselect:checked').val();
```

*OR* `name="order[route_id]"` with [Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
var str3 = $('input[name="order[route_id]"]:checked').val();
```

You need to assign it to variable `str3`, as of now you have fetched the `checked` radio button value but not using it at all.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input.timeselect:radio').change(function() {
    var str3 = $('input.timeselect:checked').val();
    str3 += $(this).text() + "\n";

    $("#timevalue").text(str3);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="new_order" id="new_order" action="/orders" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="GCE2" />
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <tbody>
        <input class="timeselect" type="radio" value="1" name="order[route_id]" id="order_route_id_1" />
        <label for="order_route_id_1">07:00</label>
        <input class="timeselect" type="radio" value="2" name="order[route_id]" id="order_route_id_2" />
        <label for="order_route_id_2">07:00</label>
        <input class="timeselect" type="radio" value="3" name="order[route_id]" id="order_route_id_3" />
        <label for="order_route_id_3">09:00</label>
        <input class="timeselect" type="radio" value="4" name="order[route_id]" id="order_route_id_4" />
        <label for="order_route_id_4">09:00</label>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button">Далее</button>
  <p> <span id="timevalue"></span>
  </p>
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Заказать" class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right" />
</form>
```

Comment: How to get the value label?

Comment: @Helga, As per your current HTML `$('input.timeselect:checked').next('label').text()`